# Layout issues in IE 6.0

Tags: css, jsp, layout, internet-explorer-6

Im having some issues with my layout in IE6 (corporate business, ideally id tell them to shove ie6 :P)

Link to the site is http://www.clickcommercial.co.uk

Ive just applied the twinhelix png fix method and that "appears" to have worked ok - but I was under the impression it should fix the issue with repeat backgrounds?

As you can see, the site works great in IE7+, firefox, safari etc :)

Any help on this is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix position of right navigation add this to your code:

```
#homebox-right { overflow:hidden }
```

Regarding other issues, I'd reccomend you to install [IE Tester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) where you can preview stuff on IE6 quite easily. You must play a little with margins for IE6.

Plus, I'd recomment to add: `img { border:none; }` to remove ugly borders from link-images.

Comment: thank you Rochal, the overflow trick worked on the layout front. Im just making some more changes to the img:border stuff to make sure that works correctly. I am using IETester now, great piece of software and thanks for the reccomendation.

Comment: Strangely enough, after adding the img {border :none; } the iepng fix is no longer working ¬_¬

Comment: you probably missing hasLayout property, try setting position:relative for these images, maybe it will help